# What is publisher Returns in Spring AMQP

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, amqp, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I've been trying my hands on Spring AMQP. And I have a couple of questions:

I'd like to know what is Publisher returns and how is it different from Publisher Confirm. Of my understanding, we have a Publisher Confirm Callback that checks the status of acks.  Now I looked at the documentation in Spring AMQP and Rabbit MQ. didn't really find or understand much on this.

And also why is it that if the message is tried to send to a non-existing queue, I don't get any sort of acknowledgement (ack/nack
) nor do I get any errors. Is there a way to setTimeouts for non-acknowledgements?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer from the link https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html :

"For unroutable messages, the broker will issue a confirm once the exchange verifies a message won't route to any queue (returns an empty list of queues). If the message is also published as mandatory, the basic.return is sent to the client before basic.ack."

In Spring AMQP if you set 'spring.rabbitmq.publisherReturns' to true this will mean messages will be 'mandatory' (unless you set mandatory to false) because of the following code:

```
    private boolean determineMandatoryFlag() {
        Boolean mandatory = this.properties.getTemplate().getMandatory();
        return (mandatory != null ? mandatory : this.properties.isPublisherReturns());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to read [this](https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html) article. There is a good description of all possible acknowledgments scenarios, including *returns* for the unrouted messages, like your non-existing queue.

From the Spring AMQP perspective you should bear in mind: https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/2.0.3.RELEASE/reference/html/_reference.html#template-confirms

> This feature requires a `CachingConnectionFactory` that has its `publisherReturns` property set to `true`.

Comment: It also helps to have a look at the section "2.2.1 
Protocol Commands (Classes & Methods)" of the spec so you can understand what "basic.consume" and "basic.get" are. https://www.rabbitmq.com/resources/specs/amqp0-9-1.pdf